# ReactJS form application: How to stop parent component from re-render? / The correct approach to share states using redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm writing a form application as my first application using React.js so I'm not a seasoned developer.

So the flow of the form is like this: 

1) There are 3 main forms (which I make it into 3 pages)

2) Submit form will only occur only at the last page. So I'm using redux approach to share states.

3) The first and the second pages have a nested form.

The problem I faced currently is with the first and second pages, when I want to render another component(nested form) inside a component(form), **all of the component state will be refreshed and I got this error below:**

```
index.js:2178 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
in form (at PersonalDetail.js:31)
in PersonalDetail (created by Connect(PersonalDetail))
in Connect(PersonalDetail) (created by Route)
in Route (at App.js:20)
in Switch (at App.js:17)
in div (created by Jumbotron)
in Jumbotron (at App.js:16)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (at App.js:15)
in App (at index.js:18)
in Provider (at index.js:17)
```

Below is my PersonalDetail.js which reside the first form (first page).

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { formUpdate } from '../actions';

import Working from './Working';

class PersonalDetail extends Component {
    renderWorkingForm(){
        if(this.props.working) {
            return (
                <Working />
                /*
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Tax Number:</label>
                    <input 
                        type="number" 
                        value={this.props.tax} 
                        onChange={event => this.props.formUpdate({ prop: 'tax', value: event.target.value })} 
                    />
                </div>
                */
            );
        }

        return;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form >
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Fullname:</label>
                    <input 
                        className="form-control" 
                        type="text" 
                        value={this.props.name}
                        onChange={event => this.props.formUpdate({ prop: 'name', value: event.target.value })}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>IC:</label>
                    <input 
                        className="form-control" 
                        type="text" 
                        value={this.props.ic}
                        onChange={event => this.props.formUpdate({ prop: 'ic', value: event.target.value })}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Nationality:</label>
                    <input 
                        className="form-control" 
                        type="text" 
                        value={this.props.nationality}
                        onChange={event => this.props.formUpdate({ prop: 'nationality', value: event.target.value })}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Are you currently working:</label>
                    <button onClick={() => this.props.formUpdate({ prop: 'working', value: true })}>Yes</button>
                    <button onClick={() => this.prop.formUpdate({ prop: 'working', value: false })}>No</button>
                </div>
                {this.renderWorkingForm}
                <Link to="/kin" className="btn btn-primary">Next</Link>
            </form>
            
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { name, ic, nationality, working, tax } = state.form;

    return { name, ic, nationality, working, tax };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { formUpdate })(PersonalDetail);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

and below is my working component class:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { formUpdate } from '../actions';

class Working extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Tax Number:</label>
                    <input type="number"  value={this.props.tax} onChange={event => this.props.formUpdate({ 
                        prop: 'tax', value: event.target.value
                    })} />
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { tax } = state.form;

    return { tax };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { formUpdate })(Working);
```

Comment: You should put some barriers to avoid your components to refresh untimely. You should check this :  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Answer (score 1):

Change `{this.renderWorkingForm}` to `{this.renderWorkingForm()}`

Comment: thank you for your respond, i've tried your instruction but it still not working :(